# Power of a matrix using Sylvester's Formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been thinking about this question and I'm really confused, I have gone through past solutions and I really understand those, but this, I don't understand. I'm to use Sylvester's formula to find $ A^{100}$ where the matrix is

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Sylvester's formula is given as $ P([A]) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} P(\lambda _{k}) Z_{k}([A])$ and $$ Z_{k}([A])=\frac{\prod\limits_{r\neq k} (A - \lambda_{k}I)}{\prod\limits_{r\neq k} (\lambda_{r}- \lambda_{k}I)} , k= 1, \dots, 100$$ $ \lambda_{k}$ are the eigenvalues.

Comment: @ Arturo Thanks....

Comment: So...? You need to find the eigenvalues of $A$, the Frobenius covariants of $A$, and then apply the formula $$f(A)=f(\lambda_1)A_1 + f(\lambda_2)A_2$$ with $f(t)=t^{100}$.

Comment: What do you mean by Sylvester's formula? Alternatively, since $A$ is symmetric you can diagonalize it and find $A^{100}$ easily.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: The Frobenius covariants are the matrices $uu^T$ where $u$ is eigenvector?

Comment: @Manos: [Here's Wikipedia's entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_covariant). Here, the Frobenius covariant, if the eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are different, are $$\frac{1}{\lambda_2-\lambda_1}(A-\lambda_1 I)\text{ and }\frac{1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}(A-\lambda_2 I).$$

Comment: Thanks guys, yea, I know Frobenius, but I'm not to use that. I'm to use Sylvester's formula. I have edited my question and the formula is in the above question

Comment: @Beat: Your formula does not make sense: $\lambda_r$ and $\lambda_k$ are scalars, so $\lambda_r-\lambda_kI$ would be the difference of a scalar and a matrix.

Comment: @Beat: I don't understand your comment; the Sylvester formula **uses** the Frobenius covariants. So how could you *possibly* "use Sylvester's formula" but not Frobenius?

Comment: @ Arturo, let me take some time to assay what you have written. Thank though.

Comment: You are utterly confused: the $n$ in the Sylvester formula is the **size of the matrix**, not the degree of the polynomial. So your $k$ only ranges from $1$ to $2$, not from $1$ to $100$.

Comment: Okay.@ Arturo. Thanks , I'm trying to still going through the whole step by step..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sylvester formula, as you write, is that if $A$ is diagonalizable, and $f(t)$ is a polynomial (in fact, any analytic function), then
$$f(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(\lambda_i)A_i$$
where $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ (hence, $n$ is the size of the matrix), and $A_i$ is the Frobenius covariant of $A$,
$$A_i = \prod_{\stackrel{j=1}{j\neq i}}^n \frac{1}{\lambda_i-\lambda_j}(A-\lambda_jI).$$

Here, your matrix is $2\times 2$, so you will have
$$f(A) = f(\lambda_1)A_1 + f(\lambda_2)A_2,$$
where
$$A_1 = \frac{1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}(A-\lambda_2I),\qquad A_2 = \frac{1}{\lambda_2-\lambda_1}(A-\lambda_1I).$$

So the first step is to find the two eigenvalues; then compute the two Frobenius covariants; then apply the formula to $f(t)=t^{100}$.

You can compute the characteristic polynomial directly (it's $(2-t)^2 - 1 = t^2-4t+3$) and find the eigenvalues; or any of the standard tricks: the determinant of $A$ is $3$, the trace is $4$, so you want to numbers that add up to $4$ and whose product is $3$: $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2 = 3$ will do.

So then
$$\begin{align*}
A_1 &= \frac{1}{1-3}(A-3I) = -\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{rr}
-1&1\\
1& -1
\end{array}\right)\\
A_2 &= \frac{1}{3-1}(A-I) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&1\\
1& 1
\end{array}\right).
\end{align*}$$
So the Sylvester formula tells you that
$$A^{100} = f(A) = \left(-\frac{f(1)}{2}\left(\begin{array}{rr}-1&1\\1&-1\end{array}\right)\right) + \left(\frac{f(3)}{2}\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\1&1
\end{array}\right)\right).$$

---

Alternatively, $A$ is diagonalizable, with eigenvectors $(1,-1)$ (corresponding to $\lambda_1=1$) and $(1,1)$ (corresponding to $\lambda_2=3$). That means that
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right) A \left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1\\
-1 & 1
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & 3
\end{array}\right).$$
Since $(PAP^{-1})^n = PA^nP^{-1}$, then
$$\begin{align*}
 \left(\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right) A^{100} \left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1\\
-1 & 1
\end{array}\right) &= \left(\left(\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right) A \left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1\\
-1 & 1
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & 3
\end{array}\right)\right)^{100} \\
&= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1& 0\\
0 & 3
\end{array}\right)^{100}.
\end{align*}$$
Computing the last matrix is easy, and then we just need to multiply by
$$\left(\begin{array}{rr}1 & 1\\-1 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$ on the left and $$\left(\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{array}\right)$$
on the right to get the value of $A^{100}$. (But this does not use Sylvester's formula).

Comment: @ Arturo, you are right. I had the same. Thanks